# Are there any frameworks like Hibernate but no cache and do directly execute SQL?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I have been trying to use Hibernate for a while. I like hibernate that it has annotation mapping ability (such as @Entity, @Column)

But I don't like it caching idea ( [How to disable hibernate caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827704/how-to-disable-hibernate-caching) said that it also cannot be disabled).

Also, I totally don't like its 'commits vs flush' idea which not directly run SQL to database when do insert/delete/update some data in database.

So, as my title, are there any frameworks like Hibernate with annotation but no cache and do directly execute SQL? It would be good if such frameworks can use in Spring.

Or, actually, Can Hibernate just disable cache or just have some configuration that can do direct SQL for every insert/delete/update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These features are on by default, because you usually need them (even though you don't realize initially).

But if you really want to disable cache and flush everything immediately:

- use `sessionFactory.openStatelessSession()` - this session does not store anything in the 1st level cache (and the 2nd level cache is off by default). Note that you can't operate collection mappings with this session.
- use `session.setFlushMode(..)` to set it to flush automatically before very query (rather discouraged).

Note that the flush mode is available only for stateful sessions - the stateless session is flushed immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me try this.

Comment: How can I config to use openStatelessSession in spring-servlet.xml/hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: shouldn't be any different - you can still inject the SessionFactory and get the session fro mthere

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is a great framework, but for more lightweight implementations I tend to use Spring JDBC:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was looking at this as well, but it has nothing like annotation for mapping columns.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/), which is a bit more direct. For an annotation-based example, [see here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/getting-started-ibatis-mybatis-0) although there are others. You can also just use pure JDBC, or via Spring if you're using Spring.

I don't understand the "not liking caching" thing.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Anyways, did you meant that you do not understand this sentence " I don't like it caching idea..."? It meant that I would like not to use any cache by Hibernate.

Comment: @SurasinTancharoen I understood what you said, I just don't have any idea *why* anyone would think caching wasn't a good idea.