# Can I disable First level cache in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

Can I disable **First Level Cache** in Hibernate, if I want?

If yes how?

Comment: "Disable first level cache in hibernate" what result will google return ? any relevant result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I stop Java or Hibernate Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162560/how-can-i-stop-java-or-hibernate-caching)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's the default and there is no way to disable the first level cache.

One thing you can do is clear it everytime you query, but i don't really see the point.

The only situation that i can think of that could give problem is when you have a session where you fetch from db a lot of object for reading and you don't need them in cache. But even then you can query for single field instead of whole object to avoid caching it

Answer (score 0):

NOPE, you can't.

You can have no interaction with the first level cache with StatelessSession. Read more about it in https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/batch/Batching.html