# Detecting N+1 query issues during testing with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, select-n-plus-1

We're using [Hypersistence Utils](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils), which is a great tool, but we're facing a challenge regarding Session cache, as mentioned in another question; it [can't be disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34163440/239613).

So, the following test fails because `findOne` fetches the object from the session cache:

```java
    @Test
    public void validateQueries() {
        // when (scenario definition)
        TestObject testObject = new TestObject(1L);
        repository.save(testObject);
        SQLStatementCountValidator.reset();
    
        repository.findOne(1L);
        SQLStatementCountValidator.assertSelectCount(1);
    }
```

There's a workaround calling `entityManager.clear()` every time `SQLStatementCountValidator.reset()` is called.

Now, the workaround is fine, but error-prone because now we have to inject EntityManager as a dependency of our tests and remember to call `entityManager.clear()` after saving all the objects that represent our scenario.

**Questions**

1. What would be the best way of achieving this?
2. Would you expect SQLStatementCountValidator to also clear the entityManager?

---

Here you can check the log statements (the last one)

```
09:59.956 [main] [TRACE] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener - Transient instance of: TestObject
09:59.957 [main] [TRACE] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener - Saving transient instance
09:59.962 [main] [TRACE] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener - Saving [TestObject#<null>]
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        test_object
        (id, creation_time, "update_time", "name") 
    values
        (null, ?, ?, ?)
10:00.005 [main] [TRACE] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushing session
10:00.005 [main] [DEBUG] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
10:00.007 [main] [DEBUG] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty checking collections
10:00.007 [main] [TRACE] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushing entities and processing referenced collections
10:00.011 [main] [TRACE] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing unreferenced collections
10:00.011 [main] [TRACE] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Scheduling collection removes/(re)creates/updates
10:00.011 [main] [DEBUG] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
10:00.011 [main] [DEBUG] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
10:00.015 [main] [TRACE] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Executing flush
10:00.015 [main] [TRACE] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Post flush
10:02.780 [main] [TRACE] o.h.e.i.DefaultLoadEventListener - Loading entity: [TestObject#1]
10:08.439 [main] [TRACE] o.h.e.i.DefaultLoadEventListener - Attempting to resolve: [TestObject#1]
10:08.439 [main] [TRACE] o.h.e.i.DefaultLoadEventListener - Resolved object in session cache: [TestObject#1]

com.vladmihalcea.sql.exception.SQLSelectCountMismatchException: Expected 1 statements but recorded 0 instead!
```

---

This is how the workaround code looks like:

```java
    @Test
    public void validateQueries() {
        // when (scenario definition)
        TestObject testObject = new TestObject(1L);
        repository.save(testObject);
        entityManager.clear();
        SQLStatementCountValidator.reset();
    
        repository.findOne(1L);
        SQLStatementCountValidator.assertSelectCount(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Transaction handling

Each test should manage transactions. So, you should remove the `@Transactional` annotation you added at the class level.

So, you inject a `TransactionTemplate` bean:

```
@Autowired
private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;
```

And, then you save the entity in one transaction:

```
@Test
public void validateQueries() {
    try {
        transactionTemplate.execute((TransactionCallback<Void>) transactionStatus -> {
            TestObject testObject = new TestObject(1L);
            repository.save(testObject);

            return null;
        });
    } catch (TransactionException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failure", e);
    }

    SQLStatementCountValidator.reset();
    repository.findOne(1L); 
    SQLStatementCountValidator.assertSelectCount(1);
}
```

You can extract the transaction handling logic in a base class method to simplify the exception handling.